# Wifi Not working with Android Virtual Box?

Tags: android, wifi, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox on my MacMini, and got the preconfigured VMLite-Android OS to go with it. It can download and search the internet, but in the settings it says there is no wifi, and the button to turn it on does not show up? I am trying to run the Amazon Appstore on it.

I think its just a hardware issue that is configured into VB that I do not know how to change. Please help!